# Obtener listado de los mime-types soportados en Android

Tags: java, android

Es posible obtener un listado de los `mime-types` soportados en el dispositivo?

Me estoy mirando [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) pero no veo como implementarlo

Comment: He econtrado código de android.webkit.MimeTypeMap https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.java.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad Android soporta la gran mayoría de los `MIME TYPES` definidos por los recursos, ver lista:

[Lista completa de tipos MIME (MIME TYPES)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Lista_completa_de_tipos_MIME)

Pero depende de las aplicaciones que tengas instaladas en tu dispositivo que son las que definen poder abrir determinado tipo de contenido.

Si deseas saber especificamente que `MIME TYPES` son soportados por determinado sistema operativo, te aconsejo revisar en el código de la clase `MediaFile` del Android SDK, como ejemplo estos 3 últimos (Marzo 2018):

- **[Marshmallow](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java#169)**
- **[Nougat](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java#184)**
- **[Oreo](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java#188)**

---

```
static {
    addFileType("MP3", FILE_TYPE_MP3, "audio/mpeg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MP3, true);
    addFileType("MPGA", FILE_TYPE_MP3, "audio/mpeg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MP3, false);
    addFileType("M4A", FILE_TYPE_M4A, "audio/mp4", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MPEG, false);
    addFileType("WAV", FILE_TYPE_WAV, "audio/x-wav", MtpConstants.FORMAT_WAV, true);
    addFileType("AMR", FILE_TYPE_AMR, "audio/amr");
    addFileType("AWB", FILE_TYPE_AWB, "audio/amr-wb");
    if (isWMAEnabled()) {
        addFileType("WMA", FILE_TYPE_WMA, "audio/x-ms-wma", MtpConstants.FORMAT_WMA, true);
    }
    addFileType("OGG", FILE_TYPE_OGG, "audio/ogg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_OGG, false);
    addFileType("OGG", FILE_TYPE_OGG, "application/ogg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_OGG, true);
    addFileType("OGA", FILE_TYPE_OGG, "application/ogg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_OGG, false);
    addFileType("AAC", FILE_TYPE_AAC, "audio/aac", MtpConstants.FORMAT_AAC, true);
    addFileType("AAC", FILE_TYPE_AAC, "audio/aac-adts", MtpConstants.FORMAT_AAC, false);
    addFileType("MKA", FILE_TYPE_MKA, "audio/x-matroska");

        addFileType("MID", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");
        addFileType("MIDI", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");
        addFileType("XMF", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");
        addFileType("RTTTL", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");
        addFileType("SMF", FILE_TYPE_SMF, "audio/sp-midi");
        addFileType("IMY", FILE_TYPE_IMY, "audio/imelody");
        addFileType("RTX", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");
        addFileType("OTA", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");
        addFileType("MXMF", FILE_TYPE_MID, "audio/midi");

        addFileType("MPEG", FILE_TYPE_MP4, "video/mpeg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MPEG, true);
        addFileType("MPG", FILE_TYPE_MP4, "video/mpeg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MPEG, false);
        addFileType("MP4", FILE_TYPE_MP4, "video/mp4", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MPEG, false);
        addFileType("M4V", FILE_TYPE_M4V, "video/mp4", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MPEG, false);
        addFileType("MOV", FILE_TYPE_QT, "video/quicktime", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MPEG, false);

        addFileType("3GP", FILE_TYPE_3GPP, "video/3gpp",  MtpConstants.FORMAT_3GP_CONTAINER, true);
        addFileType("3GPP", FILE_TYPE_3GPP, "video/3gpp", MtpConstants.FORMAT_3GP_CONTAINER, false);
        addFileType("3G2", FILE_TYPE_3GPP2, "video/3gpp2", MtpConstants.FORMAT_3GP_CONTAINER, false);
        addFileType("3GPP2", FILE_TYPE_3GPP2, "video/3gpp2", MtpConstants.FORMAT_3GP_CONTAINER, false);
        addFileType("MKV", FILE_TYPE_MKV, "video/x-matroska");
        addFileType("WEBM", FILE_TYPE_WEBM, "video/webm");
        addFileType("TS", FILE_TYPE_MP2TS, "video/mp2ts");
        addFileType("AVI", FILE_TYPE_AVI, "video/avi");

        if (isWMVEnabled()) {
            addFileType("WMV", FILE_TYPE_WMV, "video/x-ms-wmv", MtpConstants.FORMAT_WMV, true);
            addFileType("ASF", FILE_TYPE_ASF, "video/x-ms-asf");
        }

        addFileType("JPG", FILE_TYPE_JPEG, "image/jpeg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_EXIF_JPEG, true);
        addFileType("JPEG", FILE_TYPE_JPEG, "image/jpeg", MtpConstants.FORMAT_EXIF_JPEG, false);
        addFileType("GIF", FILE_TYPE_GIF, "image/gif", MtpConstants.FORMAT_GIF, true);
        addFileType("PNG", FILE_TYPE_PNG, "image/png", MtpConstants.FORMAT_PNG, true);
        addFileType("BMP", FILE_TYPE_BMP, "image/x-ms-bmp", MtpConstants.FORMAT_BMP, true);
        addFileType("WBMP", FILE_TYPE_WBMP, "image/vnd.wap.wbmp", MtpConstants.FORMAT_DEFINED, false);
        addFileType("WEBP", FILE_TYPE_WEBP, "image/webp", MtpConstants.FORMAT_DEFINED, false);

        addFileType("DNG", FILE_TYPE_DNG, "image/x-adobe-dng", MtpConstants.FORMAT_DNG, true);
        addFileType("CR2", FILE_TYPE_CR2, "image/x-canon-cr2", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);
        addFileType("NEF", FILE_TYPE_NEF, "image/x-nikon-nef", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF_EP, false);
        addFileType("NRW", FILE_TYPE_NRW, "image/x-nikon-nrw", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);
        addFileType("ARW", FILE_TYPE_ARW, "image/x-sony-arw", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);
        addFileType("RW2", FILE_TYPE_RW2, "image/x-panasonic-rw2", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);
        addFileType("ORF", FILE_TYPE_ORF, "image/x-olympus-orf", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);
        addFileType("RAF", FILE_TYPE_RAF, "image/x-fuji-raf", MtpConstants.FORMAT_DEFINED, false);
        addFileType("PEF", FILE_TYPE_PEF, "image/x-pentax-pef", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);
        addFileType("SRW", FILE_TYPE_SRW, "image/x-samsung-srw", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TIFF, false);

        addFileType("M3U", FILE_TYPE_M3U, "audio/x-mpegurl", MtpConstants.FORMAT_M3U_PLAYLIST, true);
        addFileType("M3U", FILE_TYPE_M3U, "application/x-mpegurl", MtpConstants.FORMAT_M3U_PLAYLIST, false);
        addFileType("PLS", FILE_TYPE_PLS, "audio/x-scpls", MtpConstants.FORMAT_PLS_PLAYLIST, true);
        addFileType("WPL", FILE_TYPE_WPL, "application/vnd.ms-wpl", MtpConstants.FORMAT_WPL_PLAYLIST, true);
        addFileType("M3U8", FILE_TYPE_HTTPLIVE, "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl");
        addFileType("M3U8", FILE_TYPE_HTTPLIVE, "audio/mpegurl");
        addFileType("M3U8", FILE_TYPE_HTTPLIVE, "audio/x-mpegurl");

        addFileType("FL", FILE_TYPE_FL, "application/x-android-drm-fl");

        addFileType("TXT", FILE_TYPE_TEXT, "text/plain", MtpConstants.FORMAT_TEXT, true);
        addFileType("HTM", FILE_TYPE_HTML, "text/html", MtpConstants.FORMAT_HTML, true);
        addFileType("HTML", FILE_TYPE_HTML, "text/html", MtpConstants.FORMAT_HTML, false);
        addFileType("PDF", FILE_TYPE_PDF, "application/pdf");
        addFileType("DOC", FILE_TYPE_MS_WORD, "application/msword", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MS_WORD_DOCUMENT, true);
        addFileType("XLS", FILE_TYPE_MS_EXCEL, "application/vnd.ms-excel", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MS_EXCEL_SPREADSHEET, true);
        addFileType("PPT", FILE_TYPE_MS_POWERPOINT, "application/mspowerpoint", MtpConstants.FORMAT_MS_POWERPOINT_PRESENTATION, true);
        addFileType("FLAC", FILE_TYPE_FLAC, "audio/flac", MtpConstants.FORMAT_FLAC, true);
        addFileType("ZIP", FILE_TYPE_ZIP, "application/zip");
        addFileType("MPG", FILE_TYPE_MP2PS, "video/mp2p");
        addFileType("MPEG", FILE_TYPE_MP2PS, "video/mp2p");
    }
```

---

**Como usar la clase [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html).**

Este es el ejemplo de un método el cual recibe una url, obtiene su extensión y determina el tipo de `MIME TYPE` usado:

```
  public static String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }
        return type;
    }
```

En caso de no estar soportado el `MIME TYPE` del recurso, se obtendrá un valor `null`.